# Perl Regular Expressions + delete line if it starts with #

Tags: perl

How to delete lines if they begin with a "#" character using Perl regular expressions?

For example (need to delete the following examples)

```
line="#a"
line="     #a"
line="# a"
line="    # a"
```

...

the required syntax

```
   $line =~ s/......../..
```

or skip loop if line begins with "#"

from my code:

```
open my $IN  ,'<', $file      or die "can't open '$file'  for reading: $!";
while( defined( $line = <$IN> ) ){

.
.
.
```

Answer (score 13):

You don't delete lines with `s///`. (In a loop, you probably want `next;`)

In the snippet you posted, it would be:

```
while (my $line = <IN>) {
    if ($line =~ /^\s*#/) { next; }
    # will skip the rest of the code if a line matches

    ...
}
```

Shorter forms `/^\s*#/ and next;` and `next if /^\s*#/;` are possible.

---

[`perldoc perlre`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html)

```
/^\s*#/
```

- `^` - "the beginning of the line"
- `\s` - "a whitespace character"
- `*` - "0 or more times"
- `#` - just a `#`

Comment: but how this syntax delete the line?

Comment: maybe like this     $line =~ s/^\s*#//s;   ?

Comment: @jennifer Updated answer. (`s/^\s*#//` _would_ match the line, but it wouldn't _delete_ it - it would replace the line with an empty one.)

Comment: @grawity its not work I write also  if (/^\s*#/) { print $line; } to see the remarked lines but its not print the remarked lines?

Comment: @jennifer: if you put it below the `next;`, then it's just skipped. Try `if (...) { next; } else { print $line; }` instead.

Comment: I put  if (/^\s*#/) {  next; }   else { print $line; } but now its print all lines include with "#" -:(

Comment: @jennifer Sorry, I forgot a part of the condition... It's supposed to be `if ($line =~ /^\s*#/)`.

Answer (score 7):

Based off [Aristotle Pagaltzis's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80415/perl-regex-match-and-removal) you could do:

```
perl -ni.bak -e'print unless m/^\s*#/' deletelines.txt
```

> Here, the -n switch makes perl put a loop around the code you provide
>   which will read all the files you pass on the command line in
>   sequence. The -i switch (for “in-place”) says to collect the output
>   from your script and overwrite the original contents of each file with
>   it. The .bak parameter to the -i option tells perl to keep a backup of
>   the original file in a file named after the original file name with
>   .bak appended. For all of these bits, see perldoc perlrun.

deletelines.txt (initially):

```
#a
b
     #a 
#   a
  c
         # a
```

becomes:

```
b
  c
```

Answer (score 2):

Program (Cut & paste whole thing including DATA section, adjust shebang line, run)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

while(<DATA>) {
  next if /^\s*#/;  # skip comments
  print;            # process data
}

__DATA__
# comment
data
  # another comment
more data
```

Output

```
data
more data
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$text ~= /^\s*#.*\n//g
```

That will delete all of the lines with # in the entire file of $text, without requiring that you loop through each line of the text manually.

Comment: Won't quite work if the entire file is read, as `^` refers to the beginning of the file, not the beginning of a line. This worked for me: `$text =~s/(^|\n)\s*#[^\n]*//g;` (small caveat: there will be an obsolete newline if there's a comment on line number 1)